# Create Backup of attached database file

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have Database file .mdf which is installed with setup where application installed.

All database operation Insert,Update delete works fine but only problem arise in back up.

Now i want to make back up of attached mdf file to application installed path when i click on backup button.

**Following is my connection string.**

```
<add name="MyConstring" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Database=Database;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Code which create back up.**

```
        string serverName = "";
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConString"].ToString();
        string server = builder.DataSource;
        string attachDBFilename = builder.AttachDBFilename;
        string DatabaseName = "[" + builder.InitialCatalog + "]";

        string SQLBackUp = @"BACKUP DATABASE " + DatabaseName + " TO DISK = N'" + @"d:\Data\" + "Aa.bak" + @"'";
        string svr = "Server=" + server + ";Database=master;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection cnBk = new SqlConnection(svr);
        SqlCommand cmdBkUp = new SqlCommand(SQLBackUp, cnBk);

            cnBk.Open();
            cmdBkUp.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Above code give following error only if i use database file attached.

But is gives error

> "Database does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Your database service engine account must have access to that physical file. As error suggest it's a operating system error. So You need to give proper permission on that folder or file.

See following link.

http://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/attaching-database-unable-to-open-physical-file-access-is-denied/

Write click on folder and goto security and give proper permission to the data folder so that your SQL server user can access that folder.

Comment: Sorry, Error was that " database does not exists." for above Error while i create back up.

Comment: Ok no problem. Please close the question as this will lead to different answer of question